# How to use method in array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

In my program I have file Input file and output in console. Here, I used file I/O in array but now I want to implement my program Using method.
So, How can I use method in my program? 
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
public class score {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(".");
         int jfcUserOption = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
         if (jfcUserOption == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
             File chosenFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();

             Scanner input = new Scanner( chosenFile ); 


             int n = input.nextInt();
             double[] score = new double[n];
             int bestScore = 0;


             for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                 score[i] = input.nextDouble();
                 if (bestScore < score[i]){
                     bestScore = (int) score[i];
                     }
                 }

             char grade;
             for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                 if (score[i] >= bestScore - 15)
                     grade = 'A';
                 else if (score[i] >= bestScore - 25)
                     grade = 'B';
                 else if (score[i] >= bestScore - 35)
                     grade = 'C';
                 else if (score[i] >= bestScore - 45)
                     grade = 'D';
                 else  
                     grade = 'F';

                 System.out.println("Student " + (i + 1 )+" score is " + score[i] +" and grade is " + grade);

             }


         }

    }

}
```

Comment: Try [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you want to use methods for, you have lots of options- this is why methods are useful.

A good way to think of it is to break out steps or actions into their own methods, which your main() method can call:

For example, here we define a new method findBestScore(), which we use to return an int value back to where it was called in the main() method:

```
public class score {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(".");
     int jfcUserOption = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
     if (jfcUserOption == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
         File chosenFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();

         Scanner input = new Scanner( chosenFile ); 


         int n = input.nextInt();
         double[] score = new double[n];
         int bestScore = findBestScore();

         char grade;
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
             if (score[i] >= bestScore - 15)
                 grade = 'A';
             else if (score[i] >= bestScore - 25)
                 grade = 'B';
             else if (score[i] >= bestScore - 35)
                 grade = 'C';
             else if (score[i] >= bestScore - 45)
                 grade = 'D';
             else  
                 grade = 'F';

             System.out.println("Student " + (i + 1 )+" score is " + score[i] +" and grade is " + grade);

         }


     }

}

public int findBestScore() {

    int bestScore;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        score[i] = input.nextDouble();
            if (bestScore < score[i]){
                bestScore = (int) score[i];
            }
    }

    return bestScore;
}
```

}

This doesn't compile, however, since there are some missing imports.